# HTTP response not being manipulated

Tags: python-3.x, http, httpresponse

I made a HTTP request with the following line.

```
h.request('POST', uri, body,headers={})
```

I am collecting the response in a variable.

```
res = h.getresponse()
```

after that I am trying to print the response by

```
 print(res.msg)
 print(res.status)
 print(res.read())
```

After the 3 print statment I am trying to modify the response by storing the res.read() output in a different variable to convert to a string and to do further processing.

```
  text=res.read().decode("utf-8")
```

But while doing so the decoded response is not getting stored in the variable. If I do a print on text after print(res.read()) it gives me nothing

```
 print(res.read())
 text=res.read().decode("utf-8")
 print(text)
```

The output of the above just prints me the first print statement. If I remove the first statement and do the following.

```
  text=res.read().decode("utf-8")
  print(text)
```

It gives me the required O/P. But I wanted both of them to work. So, is there a way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `res.read()`, it reads the content of the response during the print statement. On the second execution you cannot read again, unless you seek back or re-do the request.

Store the first `.read()` in a variable, then print it.

Comment: Ok, Thanks.. I stored it in a varibale and it worked..:)

Answer (score 0):

Or u can try following way.

```
from  requests import request
res = request('POST', uri, data,headers={})
print(res.text)
```